# How do I run a Tor relay under TAILS 0.23 distro?

Tags: relays, tails

I'm running TAILS 0.23 off a usb stick. The Vidalia control panel does NOT have the "Setup Relaying" button.  How can I start a Tor relay?

Answer (score 2):

TAILS is not designed to host a server, and that for security reasons. If you want to safely and securely run a Tor relay you should use [Tor-ramdisk](http://opensource.dyc.edu/tor-ramdisk)